# drop row if 3 out of 5 columns are lower than a specific value

Tags: python, imputation

I'm trying to code a line in which I drop a row in a dataframe if a pvalue (columns) is lower than 1.3 for 3 out of 5 columns. If the pvalue is greater than 1.3 in 3 out of 5 columns i keep the row. The code looks like this:

```
for i in np.arange(pvalue.shape[0]):
    if (pvalue.iloc[i,1:] < 1.3).count() > 2:
        pvalue.drop(index = pvalue.index[i], axis = 0, inplace = True)
    else:
        None
```

the pvalue dataframe has 6 columns, first column is a string and the next 5 are pvalues of an experiment. I get this error:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

and I don't how to fix this. I appreciate every help. BTW I'm a complete python beginner, so be patient with me! :) Thanks and looking forward to your solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very knowledgeable with Pandas so there probably is a better way to go about it but this should work:

By using [iterrows()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html), you can iterate over each row of a DataFrame.

```
for idx, row in pvalue.iterrows():
```

In the loop you will have access to the `idx` variable which is the index of the row you're currently iterating on, and the row values itself in the `row` variable.

Then for every row, you can iterate through each column value with a simple `for` loop.

```
for val in row[1:]:
```

while making sure you start with the 2nd value (or in other words, by ignoring the index `0` and starting with index `1`).

The rest is pretty straightforward.

```
threshold = 1.3
for idx, row in pvalue.iterrows():
   count = 0
   for val in row[1:]:
      if val < threshold:
         count += 1
   if count > 2:
      pvalue.drop(idx, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for taking the time, but unfortunately this doesn't work either. :( I geet this error: IndexError: index 3717 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3716.

Comment: I just edited something, can you check you tried the latest version?

Comment: Oh nice, it works! Thank you so much, do you mind explaining to me what exaclty you did? I'm still trying to learn and i don't understand the for loop with iterrows(). Thank you again in advance! :)

Comment: I'll add explanations in the answer then.